# Object doesn't support this property or method - IE8

Tags: jquery

I use a script for my site (bamboo.0.1.js).
It works properly in modern browsers, but in IE8 I get the errors below.
Script is not written by me.
Can someone help me to find the error?
Thank you.

```
Webpage error details

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 11
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://checkagenda.com/scripts/bamboo.0.1.js

Message: Object expected
Line: 231
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://checkagenda.com/online-birthday-nameday-reminder-calendar.php
```

Line 231:

```
<script>var site = new Bamboo();</script>
```

Comment: what is there in the said line

Comment: looks like there is a "," too much at the last entry of the object beeing interpreted